# What does the term "fixed" mean on the radio spectrum?

Tags: radio

On the [United States Radio frequency allocation chart](http://www.ntia.doc.gov/files/ntia/publications/2003-allochrt.pdf), the term "fixed" radio comes up a lot. What does that mean? Who is allowed to used "fixed"?

Answer (score 5):

Generally we distinguish two types of stations:

- Mobile, when the device is portable
- Fixed, when the device stays on one location

See [Amateur Radio Stations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amateur_radio_station#Mobile_stations) for more information:

> [image] [image]
>
> <sub>(left: fixed; right: mobile)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Fixed wireless is normally used as a term for radio communications between fixed locations such as buildings that don't move as opposed to mobile communications. One reason the allocations are treated differently is that for a fixed location it's often possible to allocate the same frequency to different regions.

For example for a given installation it may be determined for a specific frequency / power range that interference is only likely within a 10km radius, giving the possibility that the same frequency may be used hundreds of times by different users within a country as long as they are geographically far enough apart. That assumption of course can't be made for mobile communications systems that move around.

License costs are normally a combination of power and bandwidth and how far the signals are likely to emanate and also population density. I can only only speak from an Australian perspective but I believe here anyone is allowed to use fixed frequencies if you pay the license fee and it is approved. That may range from hundreds of dollars per year for a narrowband low-power license (for example courier voice communications over a limited area) and into millions for the sort of allocation you'd need for TV broadcasting over a large area.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ntia.doc.gov/files/ntia/publications/2003-allochrt.pdf ? (That is one ugly chart.)

Opposite of "mobile": the transmitter is at a fixed location. Why are there different rules for fixed and mobile? Because an interference problem caused by a mobile transmitter is a lot harder to track down.

Comment: It's better then Europe's!!! So who gets privileges to use fixed?

Comment: Exact regulation depends on the band, but there's a set of bands allocated for amateur ("ham") radio, and a training and certification process to be allowed to broadcast on them. Amateur radio is very much a community of its own.